# How to find out the specific algorithm my C++ compilers use for std::hash?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, c++14

I've got a previously Mac-only code that generates a checksum using `std::hash<std::string>` [1]. Now this code is ported to Windows. While the Mac build uses CLANG, the Windows port is compiled with GCC g++. As to be expected (with `std::hash` being implementation dependent), the result of both compilers differ:

```
# Windows: g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
std::hash("hello world"): 5577293430985752569
# Mac: Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
std::hash("hello world"): 12386028635079221413
```

*How do I find out what algorithm my compilers are using?*

The only solution I can think of is to probe all hash function implementations on some test strings and see which ones match ...

The long-term approach for this is to use identical cryptographic hash functions in both ports, of course. But it's not possible at the moment to recalculate all checksums that have been created so far by the Mac version and which have to be verifiable by the Windows port.

---

[1] Yes, using `std::hash` for this task was a bad choice in the first place.

Comment: Note that the `std::hash` implementations may return different hashes for the same input for different runs of the program.

Comment: "Clang supports use of either LLVM’s libc++ or GCC’s libstdc++ implementation of the C++ standard library." from https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/Toolchain.html#id6. Do you know which stdlib you were using?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Good point! I've learned about this new possible behavior from C++14 during research for my question. It seems this isn't implemented right now in my CLANG version, otherwise I'd have gotten a lot of angry emails already.

Comment: I've not set `stdlib` in my Makefile, so I think it's the default. That means it'll be `libc++`?

Comment: Yes, defer to Marshall's answer then. Keep in mind that if LLVM's libc++ string hash has changed between the version you used to compile and the head branch on github, you'll have to go digging to see if they were using the same hash in the version you compiled with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, using `std::hash` for this functionality was probably a bad choice. Not only is it not cross-platform, but implementations may change how they hash things from release to release. In fact, as @JohnFilleau points out, they need not even be the same for different program runs.

To answer your question directly, the hash implementations are not part of the compiler, but rather part of the standard library implementation.  On the Mac, you're almost certainly using libc++, and the hash implementation is [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/bcaa01752f5e45b9d1647aef16d74c748192f8a5/libcxx/include/__string#L1155). On Windows, you should be able to find the implementation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/42d5df07d025f1e635ee16f45b6c688394634947/stl/inc/xstring#L4581).

For both of those, you'll need to do some more searching - those are just the starting points.

Comment: When I say "not cross-platform", what I meant was "not guaranteed to give the same answers on different platforms" instead of "not available on all platforms"

Comment: It seems LLVM is using `cityhash` and the code is in: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h There's a comment reading: "FIXME: This needs to be a per-execution seed." This would explain why I didn't get any problems so far. I tried to port that hash generation code to g++ on Windows, but the generated hashes don't match. I suspect this to be an error in my code, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the code that libc++ uses. Look [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/bcaa01752f5e45b9d1647aef16d74c748192f8a5/libcxx/include/utility#L977) instead.